# cocos2d use boundingBox to check collision

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, collision, bounding-box

i use boundingBox to check collision, it's fine for touches, but not at all for collision of 2 sprites, (they are all circular but their bounding box is rect)

so is there any better ways?(it would be great if you modify my code below:

```
-(bool) isFishCollidingWithRect:(CGRect) rect
{
     FishEntity* fish;
     CCARRAY_FOREACH(fishes, fish)
     {
        if (fish.visible && CGRectIntersectsRect([fish boundingBox], rect)) {
             [fish gotHit];
             return YES;
         }
      }
      return NO;
}
```

i think there is a good way to get a smaller rect, which is in between of the original rect and a rect whose vertices just touch the circle. the size is easy to get, but the coordinate is very hard since the rect may have rotation, my math sucks

```
-(bool) isBirdCollidingWithSprite:(CCSprite*) sprite
 {
     BirdEntity* bird;
     CCARRAY_FOREACH(birdsAlone, bird)
     {
         float distance = sqrt((bird.anchorPoint.x - sprite.anchorPoint.x) * (bird.anchorPoint.x - sprite.anchorPoint.x) + (bird.anchorPoint.y - sprite.anchorPoint.y) * (bird.anchorPoint.y - sprite.anchorPoint.y)); 
         if (bird.visible && (bird.contentSize.width / 2 + sprite.contentSize.width / 2) >= distance) {
             if ([bird inBubble] == NO) {
                 [bird bubbled];
             }
             return YES;
         }
     }
     return NO;
 }
```

well, the fishes will always got hit, i believe the contentSize is the whole texture in the batch node. what should i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since they're all circles, it's pretty simple. Just check the [distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance#Geometry) between the centers of the two circles. If it's greater than the sum of the radii of the circles, the sprites aren't touching. If it's less, they're overlapping. If it's equal, they're just touching.

Comment: sounds approachable, let me try first

Comment: sorry, i used the wrong size. the birds always get hit. see my question

Comment: Where is the "anchorPoint" of each sprite? If it's not in the center of the circle, your results will be off.

Comment: well, i use a FishCache, which takes a batch node as child and initialize 50 fishes. the isFishColldingWithSprite method is also in it. each fish is initialized using initWithSpriteFrameName:@"fish1.png", fish1.png and all other png files are included in game-art.plist and game-art.png(i use zwoptx)

Comment: You could start by logging the distance between the objects, or just looking at it in the debugger. Is your distance calculation correct? Is your radius calculation correct? It should be pretty easy to verify these things.